# CommandArgument, CommandName are not executed when calling Ajax JQuery on click of asp:Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Below is my Code for Button click validation of a Textbox. i.e.,IF value of Textbox already saved in Database then show an alert else normal button events should work. For this I tried below code:

**Default.aspx page**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblGuidId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RequestID") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBarcodeNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="11" Width="230px" Text='<%# Bind("BarcodeNo") %>' Display="None"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnBar" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="Update"
OnClientClick="EnableDdlCompany();saveButtonClick();" 
CommandArgument="Save" return false;"/>
```

**Ajax JQuery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id*=btnBar]").bind("click", function () {

                var chk = {};
                chk.requestID = $("[id*=lblGuidId]").text();
                alert(chk.requestID);
                chk.barCode = $("[id*=txtBar]").val();
                alert(chk.barCode);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "ChatBoxDemo.aspx/SaveUser",
                    data: '{chk: ' + JSON.stringify(chk) + '}',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));

                        var val = data.d;
                        alert(val);

                        if (val == true) {
                            alert("Barcode No. alredy exist");  
                        }
                        else {
                            //normal function
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data.responseText);
                    },
                });
                return false;
            });
        });       
    </script>
```

**c# code:**

```
public static bool IsValidBarcodeTest(Guid? requestID, string barCode)
    {
        bool result = false;

        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Invoice.usp_tbl_Request_Select_CheckDuplicateBarcode_Test", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestID", requestID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BarcodeNo", barCode);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        result = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();

        return result;
    }

    public class Check
    {
        public Check() { }

        private Guid? requestID;
        private string barCode;

        public Guid? RequestId
        {
            get { return requestID; }
            set { requestID = value; }
        }

        public string BarCode
        {
            get { return barCode; }
            set { barCode = value; }
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static bool SaveUser(Check chk)
    {
        bool a = false;
        a = IsValidBarcodeTest(chk.RequestId, chk.BarCode);
        return a;
    }
```

When I click on button (`btnBar`), This Ajax JQuery works, but after this validation checking I want that the button should execute other events like **CommandArgument**, **CommandName**, **OnCLientClick**
 But these events are not fired when my IF condition goes to else part. 
 Please suggest what shall I change in my code so that it work as expected. 
 Please note that I can not change the events that are defined on button. I am very new in asp.net 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're never defining an OnClick server side event for btnBar.  Currently it's only executing client side code and will never hit the server side code.  If you want it to execute based on the results of your jQuery call, then you'll have do something like __doPostBack("btnBar");